# Why does rails load all javascript files in all controllers?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I´m building a small rails app and I want to use jquery instead of coffeescript so I´ve renamed all generated javascript files to .js instead.

Now, the javascript I´m adding in these js file seems to be accessible to ALL my controllers. For example, adding something in `document.ready` in my `employees.js`, this will trigger in all my views, not just the for the Employee-controller?

Why is this and is there anyway to configure this?

Comment: @where do you keep your employee.js ?

Comment: @PraveenGeorge In assets/javascripts

Comment: @marover : whatever javascript code you put inside your employee.js will be executed under all views associated with employees controller.

Comment: jQuery and CoffeeScript are not mutually exclusive

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to add the `controller` name as the `id` of the `body` `tag` of the **layout**:

```
##layouts/application.html.erb
<body id="<%= params[:controller] %>">
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

In your javascript

```
if($('#name_of_the_controller').length) { console.log('do something') }
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to use jquery instead of coffeescript

```
JQuery !== Coffeescript
```

Jquery is a framework, [coffeescript is a preprocessor](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark). They are totally different.

You can use JQuery within Coffeescript with inpunity:

```
#test.coffee
$(".element").on "click", ->
   alert "test"
```

---

> these js file seems to be accessible to ALL my controllers

It is due to [Sprockets Manifest Directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

The above is the *default* functionality for a Rails app.

It's meant so that *all* your JS/CSS assets are put into a single `application.css`/`application.js` file (single file = more efficient):

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

--

What you want is to *exclude* some files from this process.

Doing this is really simple:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= stub employees 

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :application, (:employees if controller_name == "employees" ) %>

#config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( employees.js employees.css )
```

You have to include the "excluded" files separately in your assets pipeline (as above).

Answer (score 2):

By default, all javascript files in the `app/assets/javascripts` folder is imported into the `application.js` file by the `require_tree .` statement

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This implies all your files are executed and available so long as `application.js` is referred in the main application layout

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

To get around this, remove the `//= require_tree .` statement, and then require each javascript file separately on the layouts of the views you wish to use.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'employees', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

The second culprit you might have issues with is `turbolinks`. Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster by using Rails assets pipeline to cache assets, replacing on the areas there are changes.

Unfortunately, this implies that by default, once a javascript file is loaded for a page, it stays cached (available) even when another page loads.

Even though Turbolinks has some [event hooks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#readme) that you can use to further guide your javascript file on when to be fired and when not to, these unfortunately, do not allow us to specify the exact page we want a script to be fired.

If you care so much about this fact, you could set `'data-turbolinks-track' => false`

Answer (score 0):

You can include different sets of assets by creating different layouts in `app/views/layouts`.

By changing the line `<%= javascript_include_tag "main" %>` in the layout you can include different javascript files. All of js files are typically grouped together into a single file called `application.js` by the [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), but you could also include them individually and use different layouts for each controller or even action.

You can add `layout :name_of_layout` to your controller to set the default layout for all actions in controller. If you want each action to have a different layout, you can pass it as an option to your render function: `render layout: :name_of_layout`. Look to the Edge Guide on [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#asset-tag-helpers) for more options.